# python kill python's sub-process

Tags: python

I'm using `requests_html` to scrape some site :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
    for i in range (0,30):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get('https://www.google.com')
    r.html.render()
    del session
```

Now this code creates more than 30 sub-process of *chromium* as *Python*'s sub-process. And this acquires memory, so how can I remove them?

**I don't want to use `psutil`, as it will increase one more dependency and to kill python's sub-process python may have some built in method, I want to be enlightened, if there is so**

**I can't even use exit() as I have to return and then exit(inside a method), and of course I can't exit and return**

Comment: You can use `with` as `context manager` like it is used in files opening and it will automatically closes the session just like file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try closing the session:

```
session = HTMLSession()
session.close()
```

See `requests_html.HTMLSession.close`.