# Scraper keeps chromium instances open in background

Tags: python, memory, screen-scraping, chromium

Using `requests_html import HTMLSession` I have implemented a scraper that works fine.
Checking performance I noticed the chromium instances seem to stay in memory, whereas in code everything gets overwritten.
Small as they are, I would like to intensify this and run 24/7, without clogging memory.
I've searched SO, and tried .kill to no avail.

Running python 3.7 on windows.

Any comment would be more than welcome.
Thanks ahead

```
def get_marketcap(url_path):
  from requests_html import HTMLSession
  session = HTMLSession()

  r = session.get(url_path)
  r.html.render(wait = 8, sleep = 8)
  session.close() #added after first comment

  return r.html
```

Then used as:

```
while True:
   Try:
      def get_marketcap()
      scrape...
```

Task manager

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244193/13357958

Comment: Not sure how I missed this in the first place....
Thanks for the swift reply, I can go to bed now knowing PC memory will not get clogged

Comment: I was too quick, it seems it's not solved. Another 20+ instances of chromium running in the background atm.

Comment: Edit the post with your new code.